# Look for an address in a common.Address array in Golang

Tags: go-ethereum, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Im essentially looking for a way to use bytes.Compare() but on an array of ethereum addresses that are of type `common.Address`. I need to search an array to see if another address exists in it and then add it only if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Why not use a mapping instead of an array? You could use an indexation array for iteration

Comment: i still need to be able to convert a lot of types back and forth... i need to find if an address exists inside an array of valid signers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working example of how to use `bytes.Compare` to check if an address exists in an array of `common.Address` and if it doesn't then add it to the list.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"

    "github.com/davecgh/go-spew/spew"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
)

func main() {
    list := []common.Address{
        common.HexToAddress("0x82a978b3f5962a5b0957d9ee9eef472ee55b42f1"),
        common.HexToAddress("0x7d577a597b2742b498cb5cf0c26cdcd726d39e6e"),
        common.HexToAddress("0xdceceaf3fc5c0a63d195d69b1a90011b7b19650d"),
        common.HexToAddress("0x598443f1880ef585b21f1d7585bd0577402861e5"),
        common.HexToAddress("0x13cbb8d99c6c4e0f2728c7d72606e78a29c4e224"),
        common.HexToAddress("0x77db2bebba79db42a978f896968f4afce746ea1f"),
        common.HexToAddress("0x24143873e0e0815fdcbcffdbe09c979cbf9ad013"),
        common.HexToAddress("0x10a1c1cb95c92ec31d3f22c66eef1d9f3f258c6b"),
        common.HexToAddress("0xe0fc04fa2d34a66b779fd5cee748268032a146c0"),
        common.HexToAddress("0x90f0b1ebbba1c1936aff7aaf20a7878ff9e04b6c"),
    }

    addressBytes := []byte{89, 132, 67, 241, 136, 14, 245, 133, 178, 31, 29, 117, 133, 189, 5, 119, 64, 40, 97, 229}

    var exists bool

    for i, addr := range list {
        if bytes.Compare(addr.Bytes(), addressBytes) == 0 {
            fmt.Printf("found %s at index %v", addr.Hex(), i) // found 0x598443F1880Ef585B21f1d7585Bd0577402861E5 at index 3
            exists = true
            break
        }
    }

    if !exists {
        list = append(list, common.BytesToAddress(addressBytes))
    }

    spew.Dump(list)
}
```